# How to pass a pointer to QMetaObject::newInstance() using Q_ARG

Tags: c++, qt, qmetaobject

I am trying to call an object's constructor using the QMetaObject::newInstance method. Below I have two examples of constructors I am going to use, one with pointers and one with only basic types:

```
class A : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE A(B *b, QObject * parent = 0); // Constructor A
    Q_INVOKABLE A(int x); // Constructor B
}
```

I am able to call constructor B using:

```
const QMetaObject *metaObj = &A::staticMetaObject;
metaObj->newInstance(Q_ARG(int, 0));
```

but calling constructor A does not work:

```
metaObj->newInstance(Q_ARG(B, b_ptr), Q_ARG(QObject, parent));
```

I have tried a few variations including Q_ARG(B*, b_ptr). Additionally, class B also inherits from QObject.

Comment: Have you exposed `B*` to the `QVariant` system with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`? Also the argument types are pointers so the `Q_ARG` calls must use pointer types too.

Comment: I have exposed B* using qregisterMetaType<>() and also tried using the macro. No luck either way. I can see it registered in QMetaType and have confirmed a valid ID

Comment: I believe the type should be `QObject*` in your Q_ARG